# Cannot find a string in another process memory

Tags: winapi, memory, pywin32, readprocessmemory

I am trying to explore win32 for a bit, and trying to find a string of a variable or something in memory of another process.

I have started notepad, written "hello", and cant find it in its memory dumb, also did the same with python interperter, saving a variable.

Im not sure whats even the issue here, tbh, as it seems like i went through the API allrigh...

my code:

```
from pymem.ressources.structure import MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION, SYSTEM_INFO
from ctypes import windll, wintypes as w, POINTER, c_size_t
from pymem import Pymem
from ctypes import byref, sizeof, c_ulonglong, create_string_buffer
import win32security, win32api

VIRTUALQUERYEX = windll.kernel32.VirtualQueryEx
VIRTUALQUERYEX.argtypes = w.HANDLE, w.LPCVOID, POINTER(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION), c_size_t
GETSYSTEMINFO = windll.kernel32.GetSystemInfo
READPROCESSMEMORY = windll.kernel32.ReadProcessMemory
READPROCESSMEMORY.argtypes = w.HANDLE, w.LPCVOID, w.LPVOID, c_size_t, POINTER(c_size_t)
READPROCESSMEMORY.restype = w.BOOL

MEM_COMMIT = 0x1000

MEM_IMAGE_TYPE = 0x1000000
MEM_MAPPED_TYPE = 0x40000
MEM_PRIVATE_TYPE = 0x20000


def get_system_info():
    system_info = SYSTEM_INFO()
    GETSYSTEMINFO(byref(system_info))
    return system_info


def AdjustPrivilege(priv):
    flags = win32security.TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | win32security.TOKEN_QUERY
    htoken = win32security.OpenProcessToken(win32api.GetCurrentProcess(), flags)
    id = win32security.LookupPrivilegeValue(None, priv)
    newPrivileges = [(id, win32security.SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED)]
    val = win32security.AdjustTokenPrivileges(htoken, 0, newPrivileges)
    print(val)
    print(win32api.GetLastError())

process_handle = Pymem()
process_handle.open_process_from_id(41616)
AdjustPrivilege("seDebugPrivilege")
system_info = get_system_info()
min_addr = system_info.lpMinimumApplicationAddress
max_addr = system_info.lpMaximumApplicationAddress
page_size = system_info.dwPageSize
memory_offset = min_addr
hello = b"\x68\x65\x6C\x6C\x6F"


while memory_offset < max_addr:
    memory_basic_information = MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION()
    count = c_ulonglong(0)
    if VIRTUALQUERYEX(
            process_handle.process_handle,
            memory_offset,
            byref(memory_basic_information),
            sizeof(memory_basic_information)
    ) == sizeof(memory_basic_information):
        memory_offset = memory_basic_information.BaseAddress

        memory_commit_region = memory_basic_information.State & MEM_COMMIT
        memory_type_mapped = memory_basic_information.Type & (MEM_MAPPED_TYPE | MEM_IMAGE_TYPE | MEM_PRIVATE_TYPE)
        if memory_commit_region and memory_type_mapped:
            buffer = create_string_buffer(memory_basic_information.RegionSize)
            if READPROCESSMEMORY(
                process_handle.process_handle,
                memory_offset,
                buffer,
                memory_basic_information.RegionSize,
                byref(count)
            ):
                print(hello in buffer.raw)
                if hello in buffer:
                    break
                print(buffer.raw)
            memory_offset += memory_basic_information.RegionSize
        else:
            memory_offset += page_size
```

The code is a bit long, so a short summary...

i am setting `seDebugPrivilege` privileges to my current process, looking through the `GetSystemInfo` Function to get the process memory boundries and page size, and then looping through mapped memory pages and looking for the hex value of "hello".

Am i doing anything wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Windows is Unicode-based, so as Notepad, so as almost everything in Windows, so you might want to change your `hello` variable definition.

Comment: @SimonMourier thanks for the fast comment, isnt all strings in python3 are unicode based as well?
also, i tried to encode it to unicode on some websites online, and it seems to be the same hex bytes

Comment: I don't know much about python. Maybe you can try simply hello = "hello" and use `create_unicode_buffer` instead of `create_string_buffer` over raw memory, or something like that

Comment: [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) consists of two parts: `1` A database that maps numeric values (code points) to character(-like) entities, and `2` several ways to encode code points into sequences of octets. The former is fixed while the latter allows clients to make choices. Windows settled on UTF-16LE, so you would need to add a `\0x00` after each ASCII character in your code to transform your ASCII encoding (which happens to be UTF-8) into UTF-16LE.

Comment: @IInspectable it still doesnt seem to work, but i did find some other (hard coded words) of some dll and stuff that way, so that means the encoding is now correct.

i guess i will try to do that in c++ to check if its the matter or anything, tbh at this point i dont even know what to look for..